# Where should you inject a fragment using Dagger2 subcomponents with PerFragment scope?

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-2

The Google Dagger2 docs state that you should inject a fragment in it's onAttach method:
https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html

I am running into problems doing that when trying to implement subcomponents such as an applicationComponent, and activityComponent and a fragmentComponent.

The problem is this:

Given an activity that has a viewpager contain 3 fragments...

To inject a given fragment I am creating a fragmentComponent from an existing activityComponent that was itself created in the activities' onCreateMethod.
e.g.

```
public class InjectFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentComponent fragmentComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(fragmentComponent == null){
        InjectActivity injectActivity = (InjectActivity) getActivity();
        if (injectActivity != null) {
            ActivityComponent activityComponent = injectActivity.getActivityComponent();
            if(activityComponent != null){
                fragmentComponent = activityComponent.plus(new FragmentModule());
            }
            else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot inject fragment: activityComponent is unexpectedly null.");
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot inject fragment: activity is unexpectedly null.");
        }
    }
    else{
        //fragmentComponent has been retained 
    }
}

...
```

This works fine when the activity is first created because I am not creating the fragments in the view pager until after the activityComponent has been created in the onCreate method.

This works fine on orientation change because the viewPager automatically retains the fragments and since the fragmentComponent is being retained it  doesn't need to be recreated again.

This does NOT work however when you press the home button, but the app in the background, the system kills the process and you then tap the app from the recents screen to restore it. In this case the app is throwing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot inject fragment: activityComponent is unexpectedly null.
                                                 at com.example.test.config.dagger.base.InjectFragment.onAttach(InjectFragment.java:32)
                                                 at com.example.test.features.profile.ProfileFragment.onAttach(ProfileFragment.java:54)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1363)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3217)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:3166)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:181)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:319)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:84)
                                                 at com.example.test.config.dagger.base.InjectActivity.onCreate(InjectActivity.java:16)
                                                 at com.example.test.features.profile.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:40)
```

In this scenario both the activity and fragment are being recreated from scratch but the fragment's onAttach method is being called before the activity's `onCreate` method has returned from it's call to `super.onCreate()` and had a chance to initialize it's activityComponent field.

The only way around this I can see is injecting the fragment in it's `onActivityCreated` method which would guarantee that the activity's `onCreate` has finished yet is not what what the official documentation recommends.

Where is the proper place to inject a fragment using dagger2 subcomponents that correctly implements PerFragment scope?

Comment: Have you considered FragmentLifecycleListener on the fragment manager?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No. Not sure how that would apply here.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/AppInjector.java

Comment: @EpicPandaForce The implementation I am working on is not using the dagger.android.support package at this time. Are you suggesting it is not possible to do this with my current implementation?